# Why my internet goes slow after I set the computer to sleep?

Tags: networking, drivers, kubuntu, internet

In Kubuntu 19.04, every time I put the PC to sleep and wake it up later, I get less than 1 mb/s internet speed. The only way I know to get back my real connection is by rebooting the system, which is inconvenient to do.

I guess this may be a driver issue, but couldn't figure it out by some solutions seen around here. How may I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question.